# How does memory allocation work for buffered channels

Tags: go

If I have a buffered channel like this:

```
ch := make(chan int, 1000000)
```

is 8MB of memory allocated off the bat, or does the memory allocation grow/shrink depending on the amount of data?

Comment: Allocated off the bat. If you want dynamic size, you might just want to have a slice and use a [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) to lock access to it.

Comment: Probably 8 MByte as most ints are 64 bits nowadays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The full size of the buffer (plus I believe two words for the channel itself) will be allocated up front and retained until it is garbage collected.